# Updating the .bat file in Wildfly 10 Final not working?

Tags: java, file, jboss, wildfly, nio

Hi all I am new to jboss/wildfly world I am working on a java application which supports both tomcat and wildfly where I have a piece of code which changes the file content dynamically(from java code)...when I execute the following code in tomcat,it updates the file and restarts automatically...but when I tried the same code with wildfly I don't see any updates in file content.

NOTE : I am deploying the .WAR file from admin console (the file is in .WAR).

I tried restarting the wildfly server no changes same old file content.

Here is my piece of java code,

```
Path nioPath = Paths.get(XYZScript.getPath());
                List<String> aLines = new ArrayList<>();
                aLines.add("Content 1");
                aLines.add("Content 2");
                try {
                    Files.write(nioPath, aLines, ENCODING, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
```

I found some links which says we need to redeploy the .WAR or use [Overlay](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Deployment+Overlays)
But it should be programmatic the user will change files dynamically

Answer (score 0):

During deployment JBoss / Wildfly unpacks the deployment under `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment`. It is used as a virtual file system (vfs). But it also gets deleted on undeployment.

In your case you will have to modify the war under `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` and trigger a redeployment by using marker files like `<war-name>.war.dodeploy`. See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment) for more information on marker files.